# MySQL Error 1064 without syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

After online searching I am still stuck with a confusing issue. No matter what SQL command I run on a specific table (keys) within MySQL command line I receive ERROR 1064 (42000).

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_site2 |
+-----------------+
| keys            |
| permissions     |
| profile         |
| user            |
+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basic SELECT Search:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM keys LIMIT 5;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys LIMIT 5' at line 1
```

This command works fine for the other tables in the DB, such as SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 5;
Another example is

```
SHOW COLUMNS IN keys;
```

Works fine for the others, just not in keys.

Could someone have 'locked down' the table? Is it corrupted? If so how would I be able to copy/delete the table if no MySQL commands work on it?

FYI - MySQl Server version is 5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8-log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keys` is a reserved word.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html for a complete list.

Try using backticks:

```
 SHOW COLUMNS IN `keys`;
```